# How to use Closures to get a permanent value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

If i need for a counter variable, that need to persist even if my function-component is re-render,
there is a way, without using, in React for example, state or ref, to let my updated value inside the closure to persist throught renders?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use simply global variable, but need to force updating ui which I think is against react concept.